# ¿Como conseguir una lista de functores de diferentes clases?

Tags: c++, funciones

Quiero conseguir una lista de functores de diferentes clases.
He estado intentándolo con plantillas pero sin éxito.

Esto es lo que tengo (obviamente no funciona):

```
template <typename ClassType>
struct TWraper
{
    struct FItem
    {
        ClassType *Obj;
        void (ClassType::*Delegate)(void*);
    };  
    std::vector<FItem<ClassType> > Delegates; // --> ERROR
};
```

Alguna idea para conseguirlo?
Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las funciones miembro no se comportan como las funciones libres; las segundas se pueden usar "*tal cual*" pero las primeras tienen un parámetro oculto: la instancia sobre la que se están ejecutando.

Si quieres tener un vector de funciones miembro necesitarás enlazar cada función a una instancia, puedes usar [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) para conseguirlo, el resultado de `std::bind` debe guardarse en un [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Te comparto un corto ejemplo de uso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    char a() { std::cout << this << ' '; return 'a'; }
};

struct B
{
    char b() { std::cout << this << ' '; return 'b'; }
};

int main()
{
    using delegate_char_void = std::function<char()>;
    using delegates_char_void = std::vector<delegate_char_void>;

    A a1, a2;
    B b1, b2;

    delegates_char_void dcv;
    dcv.push_back(std::bind(&A::a, a1));
    dcv.push_back(std::bind(&B::b, b1));
    dcv.push_back(std::bind(&A::a, a2));
    dcv.push_back(std::bind(&B::b, b2));

    for (const auto &f : dcv)
        std::cout << f() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHdaoQwEIWvzVMMFFYDbel6qVbQ5yjIGKOGdRMxiTeLz26T3a392dLuTTJMzvkmw2Hj@MQGlN26PgjJBttwyITSZuJ4zMlnr7WSGaEkDl@7M2dGTTkhzmCZgYKcSMB6nAAjCifQpkkSpqyBLAPTC@3vEMIUJm7sJCFEVy9kSTdEuSHqOxH1hhDSwBGFjKiHWC1kBw0feIeGV55ZzUo08HqBfqyU@ZeI5ulPi771XBbObqHOTYICcP8IGDtSCbUr69i3f@M1bHYqdz6PVvdVjewQnSfUQjbRrkgSdKQ9pX@pSle4If@orqz4LtZZRYJWTRAxJbUBtEbBroXE/5mSIPiWSOtC8oG8ydD7rpm8pGRZ13c)</kbd>, fíjate que cada `std::vector` de delegados necesita contener el mismo tipo de función.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta PaperBirdMaster!!

Answer (score 1):

Si te detienes un momento a leer el error:

```
.code.tio.cpp:11:17: error: ‘TWraper<ClassType>::FItem’ is not a template
     std::vector<FItem<ClassType> > Delegates; // --> ERROR
                 ^~~~~
```

Te darás cuenta que la clase `FItem` no es una plantilla. Por lo tanto debería ser solamente:

```
std::vector<FItem> Delegates;
```

Comment: Si, tienes razón. Gracias por la observación... El problema es que si lo hago así solo puedo conseguir las funciones de un solo tipo de clase. El tema sería poder usarlo con diferentes tipos de clases (En una sola lista). Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @IvánRodríguez probablemente puedas hacer eso con polimorfismo en lugar de plantillas.

Comment: Gracias Mateo, lo intentaré con polimorfismo!!